# Template 10:Using MasterDetail along with Hamburger Template

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, master-detail, template10

I am using template 10 for developing  a UWP app and i'm using hamburger template so when a user clicks on a particular category i would like to navigate him to a event list in a master detail view where on left is complete event list in that category and on right selected event details.There is a sample provided and its difficult to understand and don't k**now how to use the sample in my app along with hamburger navigation**.Also as an extra feature if the user clicks on a particular category the hamburger panel should hide and masterdetail view of event should come.And when user click on back button the panel should appear again with that page.

If anyone could help me it would be of great help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really detailed sample in the repository.  It has 2 examples in total.  1 a control being developed by a community member.  The other is a design based around using basic XAML with visual states along with responsive triggers for screen sizing.

I've implemented the response `non-usercontrol` variant and it works very well.  The other control based scenario has some good features and is being updated often for feature additions and corrections.

[Master Detail Sample](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Samples/MasterDetail)

Comment: Yeah but i am not able to understand the sample i mean like i want to include it in my app along with the json data i am fetching in a hamburger template.So which files should i take from this sample to include it in my app @mvermef

Comment: MainPage => VisualStates.
MasterDetailsPage => Control usage

Comment: Mainpage does it all thru visualstates, MasterDetailsPage does it using the control, should have add those descriptions with that last comment.

Comment: Even after two days of understanding i really could not get a hang of it i mean whats define in app.xaml,how to use along with json data i am getting,and most importantly use it along as a page in my hamburger template.Guess i would have to built this app without Template 10 but thanks a lot for your help @mvermef

Comment: the non-control variant has nothing to do with Template10 other than it being an example of how to integrate it into the project.  Minor items like the screen triggers are only set in the Styles for the app.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for here is a slightly simpler thing that we are able to give you. Master/Detail is certainly not splitting the atom. That being said, it's not just a drag and drop thing either. Your are going to need to take a look at the sample. Try to reproduce it exactly into a blank project. It's a great resource, but it's not a control for you to use as much as a sample for you to refer to. I certainly wish I had a simpler answer for you, but this is going to take a little effort on your side to understand the mechanics and implement it. In the end, once you pass that "ah ha" moment, I think you will look back and realize it's simpler than you thought. But until you understand how it works at a fundamental level, it's just going to continue to confuse you. I agree with @mvermef that the visual-state approach (the primary approach) is the easiest and uses the skills you will want to learn for future development, too. But, to that end, please recognize there are TWO approaches in that sample. One uses view-states and the other uses a custom user control. If I were you, don't pick the second approach. The first approach will be easy to understand, easy to implement, and wonderfully helpful to understand for other things later down the road.

Comment: Yeah as a beginner understanding it was quite difficult so ended up using Bob Tabor Master detail version which was easier and he had explained it perfectly.Maybe you guys should do a tutorial on the samples(especially the ones which are used everywhere) just like you did on Template 10 on MVA.It would be a great help for us  just like this template 10 is for us uwp developers.Thanks @jerrynixon